# Why Convert.ChangeType() not converting a date string (in dd/MM/yyyy format) into datetime type?

Tags: c#, datetime, visual-studio-2013, devexpress, type-conversion

Below is my code where I intend to populate entity data via reflection.

```
public static void SetEntityProperty(object entity, DevExpress.Web.ASPxFormLayout formLayoutControl)
{
    if (formLayoutControl != null)
    {
       Type type = entity.GetType();
       System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
       System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
       foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi in properties)
       {
          var layoutItem = formLayoutControl.FindItemByFieldName(pi.Name);
          if (layoutItem != null && layoutItem.CssClass == "ro-item") continue;

          var control = formLayoutControl.FindNestedControlByFieldName(pi.Name);
          if (control != null && control is DevExpress.Web.ASPxEdit)
          {
              var targetType = Data.IsNullableType(pi.PropertyType) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) : pi.PropertyType;
              try
              {
                 if ((control as DevExpress.Web.ASPxEdit).Value != null)
                 {
                    //here (control as DevExpress.Web.ASPxEdit).Value = "19/05/2015" and control is a read only text box
                    var value = Convert.ChangeType((control as DevExpress.Web.ASPxEdit).Value, targetType);
                    if (value != null && value is System.String)
                    {
                        value = value.ToString().Trim();
                        (control as DevExpress.Web.ASPxEdit).Value = value;
                    }
                    pi.SetValue(entity, value, null);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    pi.SetValue(entity, null, null);
                 }
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                 pi.SetValue(entity, value, null);
              }
         }
         else
              throw ex;
       }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I found few other questions related to `Convert.ChangeType` but all of there suggestions were already implemented into this code. I am using Visual Studio 2013 C#, DevExpress 14.2.6. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us what error you're getting? `Convert.ChangeType("19/05/2015", typeof(DateTime))` definitely works.

Comment: Oops, my bad. It is throwing an exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

Comment: Before the line it throws the exception, please write the string to the console and let us see what it's actually trying to parse. `19/05/2015` definitely should work.

Comment: During debug, I got this value "19/05/2015".

Comment: With quotes, or without? (Just double checking). Can you run the command directly: `Convert.ChangeType("19/05/2015", typeof(DateTime))` ? Does it give you an error this way?

Comment: Actually, this method fills data into entity using reflection. Therefore, the value and target type can be something else other than datetime too. So how will it be possible to try converting using DateTime.ParseExact() ? In addition, this method is written in internal framework and I am not allowed to change this. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;

namespace DateTimeConvert
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text1 = "19/05/2015"; //dd/mm/yyyy format
            var text2 = "05/19/2015"; //mm/dd/yyyy format
            var result = DateTime.Now;

            DateTime.TryParse(text1, out result);
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            DateTime.TryParse(text2, out result);
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            //Depending on computer's current culture format this will cause an error due to dd/MM/yyyy CULTURE format
            //DateTime date = (DateTime)Convert.ChangeType(text1, typeof(DateTime));

            var date = DateTime.ParseExact(text1, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Console.WriteLine(date);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

What happen is that you are converting a date time format of "dd/MM/yyyy". Which depends on your computer's Culture Format. You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` to instruct the correct format using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a habit out of swallowing exceptions, or even handling exceptions that you don't know about.

In this case your application is very likely unable to parse the provided date.

Don't use the Convert class to parse text strings. Use Parse methods instead.

`var resultDate = DateTime.ParseExact(((Control)DevExpress.Web.ASPxEdit).Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)`